# How to get image data from image url

Tags: asp.net, image, angular

So i have an image url from an external website. I want the image so i can send it as a file to my server. i am using angular2 in my front end and asp.net core web api in my backend. i have looked around but cannot seem to find a solution. Right now i can display the image to the user after they provide a url by using the src attribute. What i want to do is save/download the image. If i use the get request to do this, i get an error due to cors. I'm looking for a way to be able to get the image data without having to worry about cors. Is that possible and can anyone provide me links to anything that could help

Answer (score 0):

You can make a proxy server and request images via it. In response the proxy will put the pictures to your client. That will solve the cros problem.